# Casting Number to double primitive

Tags: java, reflection, casting

I'm trying to access a `HashMap<String, Number>` via reflection:

```
Serializable obj; //here goes the HashMap
String name;
...
return (double)obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("get", Object.class).invoke(obj, name);
```

but so far all I got is a casting error caused by the line above:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
```

Indeed, the map value that was accessed by the key `name` was `Integer`.So I've changed the line to:

```
return obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("get", Number.class).invoke(obj, name).doubleValue();
```

but that didn't work out either. I even got `doubleValue()` underlined as "undefined for the type Object" (but why Object if I have Number.class?).

I'm not sure what casting rules I'm breaking. Can someone, please, help me if my map entries have various number values (`Integer`, `Float`, `Double`) but I need the method to return a `double` value (primitive).

**PS**
It's not really a duplicate. My question is more general. But thank you for your input. I forgot that invoke always returns Object.

The working code is:

```
return ((Number)obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("get", Object.class).invoke(obj, name)).doubleValue();
```

Comment: What's the return type of `invoke`? Does that type have a `doubleValue` method?

Comment: You could just cast to `Integer` and the compiler will take care of making the conversion to `double` for you. Otherwise, cast to `Integer` or `Number` and then invoke its `doubleValue` method.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis The return type should be Number since I try to get the Number element from a HashMap. So it should have a doubleValue method. The actual value of the HashMap element in this case is Integer as I wrote before.

Comment: Please pull up the javadoc of the method and verify. (It's `Object`, not `Number`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the wrong assumption that there was a relationship between the `Class` object you pass to `getDeclaredMethod` and the return type of `Method.invoke`.
The `Class` objects you pass to `getMethod` or `getDeclaredMethod` describe the *parameter* types of the method, not the return type.
Further, while you may pass arguments of a subtype of the declared parameter type, you have to specify exactly the declared parameter type.

The parameter type of [`Map.get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get-java.lang.Object-) is `Object`, invariably, so you have to specify `Object.class`, regardless of which actual key you will pass to `invoke`.

Further, due to type erasure, the reflective return type will always be `Object`, regardless of the actual `Map`’s parametrization.
Not that it matters, [`Method.invoke`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object...-)’s declared return type is always `Object`, as different `Method` instances may represent different methods.

So when you have a `HashMap<String, Number>`, you can rely on the returned objects to be `Number` instances, but not necessarily `Double` instances. As you experienced, there could be `Integer` instances. So what you have to do, is to type-cast to `Number`, followed by invoking `doubleValue()`:

```
return ((Number)obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("get", Object.class)
        .invoke(obj, name)).doubleValue();
```

That said, if you know that the object implements the `Map` interface, there is no reason to use Reflection at all:

```
return ((Number)((Map<?,?>)obj).get(name)).doubleValue();
```

does the job much more efficient.

Comment: Thank you for a very enlightening reply.